# For unique values in one column get the total count of unique values in another column

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have two a pyodbc row object that looks like:

```
('Emp1', 'Absent')

('Emp1', 'Absent')

('Emp1', 'Present')

('Emp2', 'Present')

('Emp2', 'Present')

('Emp2', 'Absent')

('Emp2', 'Present')

('Emp2', 'Absent')
```

I would like to count the number of "Present" and "Absent" for each unique employee like:

```
Emp1: Absent= 2, Present= 1

Emp2: Absent = 2, Present = 3
```

I tried:

```
new = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in new:
    new.append(row[0])
for x in new:
    print(x, row[1].count("Present"))
    print(x, row[1].count("Absent"))
```

But it returned a row of 000000's

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```py
import collections
import itertools

data = [
    ('Emp1', 'Absent'),
    ('Emp1', 'Absent'),
    ('Emp1', 'Present'),
    ('Emp2', 'Present'),
    ('Emp2', 'Present'),
    ('Emp2', 'Absent'),
    ('Emp2', 'Present'),
    ('Emp2', 'Absent'),
]
sorted_data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1])) # sort our data
employees = collections.defaultdict(dict)
# group by employee
for employee, employee_group in itertools.groupby(sorted_data, lambda item: item[0]):
    # group by category
    for category, category_group in itertools.groupby(employee_group, lambda item: item[1]):
        employees[employee][category] = sum(1 for _ in category_group)

print('employees', employees) # employees defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Emp1': {'Absent': 2, 'Present': 1}, 'Emp2': {'Absent': 2, 'Present': 3}})
```